# Grab the first 3 characters from a parameter, and make a new parameter from that then you it to find items that are LIKE it?

Tags: sql-server, parameters

The first 3 characters of an Item is the Price Group. This is for a stored procedure so I need it to find all items within the price group based on the item itself.

```
DECLARE @ItemNumber VARCHAR(30) = 'ABC1234'
DECLARE @PG VARCHAR(3) = SUBSTRING(@ItemNumber, 1, 3)

SELECT * 
FROM Coupons (NOLOCK)
WHERE CouponType = 'PriceGroup'
and Description like (@PG)
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but any reason for the use of `NOLOCK`? Are you aware that it can (and will) cause your results to be incorrect? As what what you appear to be asking *"Is there a way to grab the first 3 characters from a parameter"*, have you considered `LEFT`?

Comment: You need to add the wildcard after your parameter to correctly use the 'LIKE'  eg "and Description like (@PG + '%')"

Comment: Yes I know that NOLOCK is bad practice but the place I work told me they want me to do it anyway. Also adding the + '%' worked for me. Thanks

Comment: @AustinMarlow If you must use hints, you might as well start using them with the most current syntax and not the deprecated syntax. Hints should use the form "with (hint)". And beware the the people who tell you that you must do this. It is NOT standard nor best practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using LIKE I can only assume you are looking for the first 3 characters anywhere in the Description. Something like this will work.

```
DECLARE @ItemNumber VARCHAR(30) = 'ABC1234'

SELECT * 
FROM Coupons
WHERE CouponType = 'PriceGroup'
and Description like '%' + LEFT(@ItemNumber, 3) + '%'
```

Also, NOLOCK is very rarely a good idea. https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/ But if you insist on using it, you need to include the WITH keyword for query hints. Omitting them is deprecated.